# e-form add row presents at top of table

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an angularjs application and am using e-form to view/add/edit rows in a table.  When I choose add, I would like the new row to present at the top of the list rather than the bottom of the list.  Once the row is added, it should sort according to the sort order I have designed.  But for usability, it's friendlier for the user if the new row is at the top of the page.  Any ideas, suggestions, etc. greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
      <md-button type="button" class="md-accent md-raised" ng-click="searchText=undefined; addContributor()">+ Add Contributor</md-button>
      </div>
    </md-card-header-text><label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label><button-xs ng-click="searchText=undefined">Clear</button-xs>
  </md-card-header>
    <md-card-content class="px-helper-pt-0">
    <md-table-container>
      <table md-table md-progress="vm.contributors">
        <colgroup><col></colgroup>
        <colgroup><col></colgroup>
        <colgroup><col></colgroup>
        <colgroup><col></colgroup>
        <thead md-head md-order="vm.query.order">
        <tr md-row>
          <th ng-show=false md-column md-order-by="id" class="md-body-2"><span class="md-body-2">Id</span></th>
          <th md-column md-order-by="name" class="md-body-2"><span class="md-body-2">Name</span></th>
          <th md-column md-order-by="role" class="md-body-2"><span class="md-body-2">Role</span></th>
          <th md-column class="md-body-2"><span class="md-body-2">Edit</span></th>
          <th md-column class="md-body-2"><span class="md-body-2"></span></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr dir-paginate="item in vm.contributors | filter:{searchField:searchText} | itemsPerPage: 25 | orderBy: vm.query.order">
          <td ng-show=false  md-cell><span editable-text="item.id" e-disabled e-name="id" e-form="rowform">{{item.id}}</span></a></td>
          <td md-cell><span editable-text="item.name" e-name="name" e-form="rowform">{{item.name}}</span></a></td>
          <td md-cell><span editable-text="item.role" e-name="role" e-form="rowform">{{item.role}}</span></a></td>
          <td style="white-space: nowrap">
            <form editable-form name="rowform" onbeforesave="saveContributor($data, item.id)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" shown="inserted == item">
              <md-button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" class="md-accent md-raised">save</md-button>
              <md-button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</md-button>
            </form>
            <div class="buttons" ng-show="!rowform.$visible">
              <md-button type="button" class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="rowform.$show()">edit</md-button>
              <md-button class="md-warn md-raised" ng-confirm-message="Are you sure you want to delete?" ng-confirm-click="deleteContributor(item.id)">Delete</md-button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </md-table-container>
```

controller:

```
activate();

function activate() {
  vm.promises = [getContributors()];

  return $q.all(vm.promises).then(function() {
    logger.info('Activation', 'Contributors Controller', 'Template Rendered');
  });
}

vm.query = {
  order: 'name'
};

$scope.deleteContributor = function(contributorId) {
  contributorsFactory.deleteContributor(contributorId).then(function(status) {
    console.log(status);
    if (status !== 409) {
      $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple().textContent('Deleted Contributor' + contributorId).theme('success').position('left top'));
      contributorsFactory.deleteItemFromArrayById(contributorId, vm.contributors);
    }
    window.setTimeout(function() {window.location.reload();}, 1000);
  });
};

$scope.saveContributor = function(data, id) {
  contributorsFactory.updateContributor(JSON.stringify(data), id).then(function(res) {console.log(res);});
  $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple().textContent('Form Saved').theme('success').position('left top'));
  window.setTimeout(function() {window.location.reload();}, 1000);
};

$scope.addContributor = function() {
  $scope.inserted = {
    value: ''
  };
  vm.contributors.push($scope.inserted);
};

function getContributors() {
  var item;
  return dojo.contribCollection()
    .then(function(data) {
      vm.contributors = data;

      angular.forEach(vm.contributors, function(e) {
        e.searchField = e.id + ' ' + e.name + ' ' + e.role + ' ';
```

Comment: so you're working with `$scope` or `controlerAs`?

Comment: This is from my route.js  function getStates() {
    return [
      {
        state: 'contributors',
        config: {
          url: '/contributors',
          templateUrl: 'app/contributors/contributors.html',
          controller: 'ContributorsController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          title: 'Contributors',
          ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Contributors'

Comment: I don't want a prepend or an upshift.  The table will resort by contributor name once the new item is added.  I just want the add row fields to be at the top of the page so the user doesn't need to scroll down to the bottom to find it.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want new item display in the first . You can try use splice

```
vm.contributors.splice(0,0,itemyouwanpush)
```

And why you mixing $scope with controllerAs? Just use one . In html you change ng-click to

```
vm.addContributor()
```

And in controller

```
 vm.addContributor()=function(){
      vm.contributors.splice(0,0,itemyouwanpush)

}
```

And dont forget 
 `var vm = this;` in controller

Comment: controller:  $scope.addContributor = function() {
      $scope.inserted = {
        value: ''
      };
      vm.contributors.push($scope.inserted);
      vm.contributors.splice(0,0,contributor);
    };  Did not correct the issue

Comment: Yes because you mixing controllerAs with $scope . Plese edit your question and add more code in it

Comment: Added full code from html and controller (except for very beginning of controller)

Comment: Thank you Thanh for the help.  I did have var vm = this; in the controller I just didn't include that section of the file.  This is the code I used to resolve the issue, mostly taken from your help:  vm.contributors.splice(0, 0, $scope.inserted = {value: ''});

Comment: @PSomers I'm glad for have . But i think you should'n mixing $scope with controllerAs syntax . Just use one . You can see for more infomation in here : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers . And if it helpful for you . Please accept for me ^^

Comment: Thanh, I am not mixing $scope and controllerAs in the controller.  The controllerAs is in the factory.js.  This is the way we have built our app.  I'm very new to AppDev so it's possible I didn't answer your original question with complete information.  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that resolved the issue:

controller.js

vm.contributors.splice(0, 0, $scope.inserted = {name: '', role: ''});